# Asymptotic Growth of Generalised Catalan Numbers

Tags: combinatorics, asymptotics, generating-functions, catalan-numbers

I'm trying to understand the asymptotic behaviour of a family of integer sequences related to the Catalan numbers $\left( c_n \right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$.  The OEIS suggests that these are known as generalised Catalan numbers; I'm not sure if this term is used more widely.  I think I've been able to figure a lot of this out by myself, but I'd appreciate suggestions for any suitable reference I could look up to better understand things.

Recall that the Catalan numbers have generating function $F(z)$ where $$F(z) = \frac{1-\sqrt{1-4z}}{2z} .$$ Now for any integer $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ let the 'generalised` Catalan numbers of type $k$ be the integer sequence $(c^{[k]}_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ with generating function $F_k(z)$ satisfying $$F_k(z) = \frac{1}{1-kzF(z)}.$$

For example, $(c^{[1]}_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ are just the (ordinary) Catalan numbers and $(c^{[2]}_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ are the central binomial coefficients.  In these two cases we have exact formulas:

$$ c^{[1]}_n = \frac{1}{n+1} {2n \choose n}$$

and

$$ c^{[2]}_n = {2n \choose n} .$$

We can use these, together with [Stirling's approximation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StirlingsApproximation.html), to show that

$$ c^{[1]}_n \sim \frac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi n^3}} $$

and

$$ c^{[2]}_n \sim \frac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi n}}.$$

For other $k$ I'm not aware of any similar formulas.  The case $k=0$ is trivial as $c^{[0]}_n = 0$ for all $n > 0$.  And I assume the remaining cases require singularity analysis, which is something I'm not really familiar with.

I've been told -- though I don't think I've ever seen a proof -- that when an integer sequence $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ has a generating function $P(z)$ the asymptotic behaviour of the sequence depends on the smallest non-zero singularity $z_0$ of $P(z)$.  In particular, I understand that in this case $a_n \sim \theta(n) |z_0|^{-n}$ for $\theta$ some subexponential function.

In the case of $F_k(z)$ as long as $k \neq 0$ there are two singularities: a pole at $z=\frac{k-1}{k^2}$ and a branch point at $z=\frac{1}{4}$.  Since $$0 < \left|\frac{k-1}{k^2}\right| < \frac{1}{4} $$ for all integers $k$ other than those in $$I := \left\{ -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2 \right\}$$ this means that for $k \notin I$ we should have $$c^{[k]}_n \sim \theta_k(n) \left( \frac{k^2}{k-1} \right)^n . $$

I'm not sure how in general one would go about finding $\theta_k$.  In fact, by trial and error I've persuaded myself that -- again, for $k \notin I$ -- we have $$ c^{[k]}_n \sim \frac{k-2}{k-1} \left( \frac{k^2}{k-1} \right)^n $$ but again I'm not sure how to prove this to be true.

The remaining cases should, I assume, be of the form $c^{[k]}_n \sim \theta_k(n) 4^n$.  This is true for $k=1$ and $k=2$ (shown above).  And it's apparently true for the case $k=-1$, as [Fung Lam](http://oeis.org/A126983) (on the OEIS) gives the estimate $$c^{[-1]}_n \sim - \frac{4^n}{9 \sqrt{\pi n^3}}.$$

I've not been able to even guess what the subexponential term should be for the remaining three cases.

In summary then, I really have two questions:

1. Are the particular estimates for the asymptotic growth of $c^{[k]}_n$ that I suggest above correct?  Is anything known about the cases $k \in \{-4,-3,-2\}$?
2. In general, how can I derive expressions for the asymptotic behaviour of an integer sequence if I know its generating function?  (I suspect what I'm really looking for here is the name of a useful textbook...)

Comment: The textbook part is easy -- *Analytic Combinatorics* by Flajolet & Sedgewick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  references  here are  to  the  book *Analytic  Combinatorics*  by
Flajolet and Sedgewick. Suppose we have

$$F(z) = \frac{1-\sqrt{1-4z}}{2z}$$

and we are interested in the asymptotics of the coefficients of

$$F_k(z) = \frac{1}{1-kzF(z)}.$$

We restrict  to $k\ge 3$  since $k=1$ and  $k=2$ have closed  forms in
terms  of binomial  coefficients  (ordinary  Catalan numbers,  central
binomial coefficients). We obtain

$$\frac{1}{1-k(1-\sqrt{1-4z})/2}
= \frac{1}{1-k/2+k\sqrt{1-4z}/2}
\\ = \frac{1-k/2-k\sqrt{1-4z}/2}{(1-k/2)^2-k^2(1-4z)/4}
= \frac{1-k/2-k\sqrt{1-4z}/2}{1-k+k^2z}
\\ = \frac{1}{1-k} \frac{1-k/2-k\sqrt{1-4z}/2}{1-zk^2/(k-1)}.$$

We thus obtain for the desired coefficient the closed form

$$\frac{k-2}{2k-2} \frac{k^{2n}}{(k-1)^n}
+ \frac{k}{2k-2} [z^n] \frac{\sqrt{1-4z}}{1-zk^2/(k-1)}.$$

We  require the  asymptotics  of the  remaining  coefficient. Now  the
square root term has radius of convergence $1/4$ and the rational term
$(k-1)/k^2.$ Furthermore with $k\ge 3$ we have $1/4 \gt (k-1)/k^2.$ We
are  thus   justified  in  applying  **Theorem   VI.12**  ("elementary
methods") for our purpose, taking

$$\alpha = 1/4 \quad\text{and}\quad \beta = (k-1)/k^2,
\quad\text{as well as}
\\ a(z) = \sqrt{1-4z} \quad\text{and}\quad
b(z) = \frac{1}{1-zk^2/(k-1)}$$

We get for the asymptotics

$$a(\beta) [z^n] b(z) = \sqrt{1-4(k-1)/k^2} \frac{k^{2n}}{(k-1)^n}.$$

Joining the two terms we find

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{k-1} 
\left(k-2 + k \sqrt{1-4(k-1)/k^2}\right)
\left(\frac{k^2}{k-1}\right)^n.}$$

The coefficient on the exponential is close to one for $k$ large. What
we see here is  that the two contributions were of  the same order and
we may not omit either one of  them. Consulting the quoted text we see
that  in order  for the  proof to  go through  the value  $\beta$ must
retain its sign (as opposed to merely being the radius of convergence,
which is positive).  This means the  above result also holds for $k\le
-5.$

Remaining case is  $-4\le k\le -1.$ We observe that  $a(z)$ and $b(z)$
have reversed their roles and we require

$$[z^n] \sqrt{1-4z} = [(-z)^n] \sqrt{1+4z} = 
(-1)^n 4^n {1/2\choose n} = (-1)^n \frac{1}{2n} 4^n {-1/2\choose n-1}
\\ = (-1)^n \frac{1}{2n!} 4^n \prod_{j=0}^{n-2} (-1/2-j)
= - \frac{1}{2n!} 2^{n+1} \prod_{j=0}^{n-2} (2j+1)
\\ = - \frac{1}{n!} 2^n \frac{(2n-3)!}{(n-2)! 2^{n-2}}
= - \frac{4}{n} {2n-3\choose n-1}.$$

We get for the asymptotics

$$\frac{k-2}{2k-2} \frac{k^{2n}}{(k-1)^n}
- \frac{k}{2k-2} \frac{1}{1-k^2/(k-1)/4} 
\frac{4}{n} {2n-3\choose n-1}$$

or

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\frac{k-2}{2k-2} \frac{k^{2n}}{(k-1)^n}
+ \frac{8k}{(k-2)^2} \frac{1}{n} {2n-3\choose n-1}.}$$

Now for the binomial coefficient we have

$$\frac{(2n-3)!}{n! (n-2)!} = 
\frac{(n+1)n(n-1)}{2n(2n-1)(2n-2)} \frac{1}{n+1} {2n\choose n}
\sim \frac{1}{8} \frac{4^n}{n^{3/2} \sqrt{\pi}}.$$

and we have the alternate asymptotic

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\frac{k-2}{2k-2} \frac{k^{2n}}{(k-1)^n}
+ \frac{k}{(k-2)^2} \frac{4^n}{n^{3/2} \sqrt{\pi}}.}$$

The modulus  of $k^2/(k-1)$ with $k$  in the given range  is less than
$4$  and hence  the  second  term that  originates  with the  binomial
coefficient dominates eventually.